# Alternate openpyxl with xlsxwriter

Tags: python, charts, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to build some charts using xlsxwriter as shown in the following code, but I also get to use openpyxl before reaching out this code. The error is:

AttributeError: 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'add_chart'

I'm understanding that it's trying to run this with openpyxl instead of xlsxwriter, is there a way to unistall openpxl before running this part? or can i force it to run with xlsxwriter? or anyother way?

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(output_path + '\\' + input)
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['New_Freq']
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'column'})
chart.add_series ({'values': '=New_Freq!$A:$B'})
worksheet.insert_chart('G2', chart)
```

Comment: What is `writer`? Please upload the full code to give context.

Comment: You appear to be overwriting a workbook created by XlsxWriter with one created in Pandas. Maybe that is what you want but it looks like an error. Also, if you do want Pandas to explicitly create an XlsxWriter file you should specify it as the Excel engine: `pd.ExcelWriter('file.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')`.